# How to play .m3u8 in a HTML page..

Tags: html, m3u8

I have tried video tag, jw player. But nothing helped.

jw code,

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jwplayer.js'></script>

<div id='mediaplayer'></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> jwplayer('mediaplayer').setup({ 'width': '480', 'height': '270', 'file': 'http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8', 'image': '/thumbs/sample.jpg', 'modes': [ {type: 'html5'}, {type: 'flash', src: '/player.swf'}, {type: 'download'} ] }); </script>
```

video tag,

```
<video width="300" height="200" controls>   <source src="http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8"> </video>
```

Can anybody suggest ideas to play .m3u8 in HTML page..

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the MIME type attribute in the video tag: type="application/x-mpegURL

```
<video width="300" height="200" controls>   <source src="http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8"
type="application/x-mpegURL> </video>
```

Comment: Even after setting MIME type, it doesn't work. Verified with chrome(Version 35.0.1916.114 m), IE(9.0.811), safari(5.1.7) browsers. Player is displaying without displaying video. Even I pressed play button there is no response.