# Create movie auto-play in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//releases.flowplayer.org/7.0.4/commercial/skin/skin.css">
    <style>

   </style>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//releases.flowplayer.org/7.0.4/commercial/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//releases.flowplayer.org/hlsjs/flowplayer.hlsjs.min.js"></script> 
  <script>
  flowplayer(function (api) {
    api.on("load", function (e, api, video) {
      $("#vinfo").text(api.engine.engineName + " engine playing " + video.type);
    }); });
  </script>

<div class="flowplayer fixed-controls no-toggle no-time play-button obj"
      style="    width: 85.5%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: 7.2%;
    margin-top: 6%;
    z-index: 1000;" data-key="$812975748999788" data-live="true" data-share="false" data-ratio="0.5625"  data-logo="">
      <video autoplay="true" stretch="true">

         <source type="application/x-mpegurl" src="http://live.wmncdn.net/safaritv2/live2.stream/index.m3u8">
      </video>   
   </div>
```

Hello friends, how can I add this autoplay script?

[I found this script from this conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074975/how-to-play-m3u8-in-a-html-page)

Honestly, I do not know jQuery, thank you for helping me. I have been working for 6 hours, but I could not.    :)

Comment: I found the link "http://live.wmncdn.net/safaritv2/live2.stream/index.m3u8" is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I give you a sample code for your reference:

```js
$( document ).ready(()=>{
     let player= videojs('hls-example',
     {autoplay:true,controls:true,liveui:true,muted:true});
  }
);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>

<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.18.1/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.18.1/video.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <video class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered" id='hls-example' width="300" height="200">
            <source src="https://cph-p2p-msl.akamaized.net/hls/live/2000341/test/master.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```